# cssnext not write file

Tags: node.js, docker, gulp

I run cssnext (1.3.0) with gulp (3.8.11) on docker (1.6) container (official node image) and my OS is ArchLinux (host). The node version is 0.10.38. I have a problem, i can't solve. This is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp    = require('gulp');
var cssnext = require("gulp-cssnext");

gulp.task("css4Tocss", function() {
gulp.src("css/index.css")
   .pipe(cssnext({
        compress: true
   }))
   .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"))
});
```

When i run:

```
gulp css4Tocss
```

i get the following error:

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at LazyResult.run (/app/node_modules/cssnext/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:193:24)
    at LazyResult.sync (/app/node_modules/cssnext/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:179:32)
    at LazyResult.stringify (/app/node_modules/cssnext/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:210:14)
    at LazyResult._createClass.get (/app/node_modules/cssnext/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:232:25)
    at cssnext (/app/node_modules/cssnext/index.js:220:20)
```

If you have an idea, i'm interested ^^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's an [issue](https://github.com/cssnext/gulp-cssnext/issues/4) in the latest version of this module.  Downgrading to `"gulp-cssnext": "0.6.0"` fixed this issue for me.

Either that or you can follow the issue above!

Comment: Thanks, i'm pass "gulp-cssnext" to 0.6.0 and it work.